# Make my Laravel Collective Destroy button next to the rest of buttons

Tags: html, laravel

I have a table with 3 action buttons, I want the "Destroy" button to be next to the rest but it gets placed under the other two, how could I fix it?

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Publishing Date</th>
        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($books as $book)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{$book->fec_pub}}</td>
        <td class="td-actions text-center">
        <a href="/books/show" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
        </a>
        <a href="/books/{{$book->id}}/edit" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        </a>
        {!! Form::open(['route'=> ['books.destroy', $book->id], 'method'=>'DELETE']) !!}
        {!! Form::button('<i class="material-icons">close</i>', ['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
       </td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>` generated by `{!! Form::open` has a default display of `block`. You need to add the style of `display: inline-block` to the form in order for the button to go beside the others.

This can be done with the `d-inline-block` Bootstrap 4 class as well.